# Media file not being found in production Django-Heroku: returns 404 error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have some default images in my media folder in Djang. However, on my website, I cannot see the images being displayed and I get a 404 error.

Now my project folder tree is(project name is register):

```
register
-- live-static
---- static-root
---- media-root
------ defaults
```

and my media and static files settings are:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ 
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'live-static', 'static-root')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'live-static', 'media-root')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
```

And inside my `urls.py` in the same folder as `wsgi.py` I have:

```
urlpatterns = [ 
    """
    My other urls
    """ 
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT ) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My static files are loaded and the server can retrieve them, however, the images that I added to my folders in `media-root` are returning a 404 error by the server. Why is this happening as I have already also set `STATICFILES_STORAGE` as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is something I got hung up on with my first Heroku deploy. Since Heroku projects run on dynos, they eventually go to sleep if there is not a request within a certain period of time. When the dyno restarts, it does not save the uploaded data. Here is a link to some information from Heroku: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

What I ended up doing is setting up an Amazon S3 bucket for storage of these files. Dennis Ivy did a video explaining how to do this: https://youtu.be/inQyZ7zFMHM

Comment: Yes I realized this myself, thanks for the video link as well. Turn out Whitnoise only stores static files uploaded by admin.

Answer (score 0):

> Update your setting file like this
>
> there is no need to change any thing else
>
> in urls.py change the urlpatterns to. remove STATIC_ROOT etc

```
+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> in setting.py like this. remove other file settings like STATICFILES_STORAGE

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'



STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
]
#if your media folder is in public_html which contain the media file
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/yourusername/public_html/media'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/yourusername/public_html/static'

#if your media folder is in other_folder which contain the media file
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/yourusername/other_folder /media'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/yourusername/other_folder /static'
```

Comment: Their application is deployed on Heroku which has an ephemeral file system. Any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted.https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted